# php string replace remove & add word at the end

Tags: php, html, arrays, str-replace

Maybe really simple, but I can't get my head around how to use `str_replace` to do the following on multiple phrases:

*Note:* It is always the last word that I want to retain (i.e. London, Birmingham & Scotland or any others).

**Example Phrases**

> I Love London
>
> Living near Birmingham
>
> Playing by Scotland

**To be turned into:**

> In London Today
>
> In Birmingham Today
>
> In Scotland Today

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably not going to be able to use `str_replace()` with out a lot more code:

```
preg_match('/\w+$/', $string, $match);
echo $match[0];
```

Or as an example replace:

```
$result = preg_replace('/.*?(\w+)$/', 'In $1 Today', $string);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a regular expression and `preg_replace()` to do it in one step:

```
print preg_replace('/.* (\w+)\W*/', 'In \1 today', "I love London");
```

I made it a bit more robust than you anticipate, by ignoring any punctuation or spaces after the last word.

Or, to use the same regexp with a whole list of strings:

```
$data = array("I love London", 
    "I live in Birmingham!",
    "Living near Birmingham!",
    "Playing by Scotland..."
    );

$results = preg_replace('/.* (\w+)\W*/', 'In \1 today', $data);
foreach ($results as $string)
    print $string, "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo str_replace(array("I Love London","Living near Birmingham","Playing by Scotland"), array("In London Today","In Birmingham Today","In Scotland Today"),  "I Love London Living near Birmingham Playing by Scotland");
```

Comment: need to put here your string variable besides "I Love London Living near Birmingham Playing by Scotland"

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explain how it works, and describe when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.